# python requests check if a file downloaded correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7, download, python-requests

I am using `requests` lib to download some images from a site.
My code would check file size after downloaded.
sample code:

```
def download(url, store_dir):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)

    filename = r.headers.get('content-disposition').split('=')[1]

    real_length = int(r.headers.get('content-length'))

    wholepath = os.path.join(store_dir, filename)

    with open(wholepath, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
        f.close()

    if os.path.getsize(wholepath) != real_length:
        print('size error')
        print('status_code: %s' %r.status_code)
        print('headers: %s' %r.headers)
        print('url"%s' % url)
        print('orgin:', r.headers['content-length'], 'now',os.path.getsize(wholepath))
        self.download(url, store_dir)
```

But I usually found that an image file was broken even if `os.path.getsize(wholepath) == real_length` .
 
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nearly 4 years. I forgot this question until recieve a downvote today .

Let me end this question:

### There is no perfect way to validate a file without its hash string.

But if you are crawling file from a website, you can try to find if there is a string on the page/url which looks like a md5/sha1, and take it a try. With luck, it is the file hash, you can validate the file by it. With no luck, no way.